# Randomize slideshow images

Tags: php, drupal, slideshow, swfobject

I have this drupal slideshow which pulls images from a folder sequentially by image title (01_title.jpg, 02_title.jpg, etc..)

I was wondering if there is an easy way to randomize the images, so it starts with a different image every time you refresh the page?

you can view the slideshow here http://www.rubensteinpr.com/

Thanks!

```
<div id ="index">
        <?php
            // Note that !== did not exist until 4.0.0-RC2
            $desired_extension = 'jpg'; //extension we're looking for 
            $banner_imgs_array = array(); // array of banner images
            $banner_imgs = ''; // sting of banner images names comma dileneated

            if ($handle = opendir(file_directory_path().'/banner_imgs')) {

                /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
                while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..")) { 
                      $fileChunks = explode(".", $file); 
                      if($fileChunks[1] == $desired_extension) //interested in second chunk only 
                      {       
                        $banner_imgs_array[] = $file;
                      } 
                    } 
                }

                closedir($handle);

                $banner_imgs = implode(',', $banner_imgs_array);
            }
        ?>
        <div id="banner"><img src="<?php print file_directory_path(); ?>/temp_banner.jpg" width="702" height="310" border="0"></div>
        <div id="bannerText">media relations &bull; strategic planning &bull; digital communications &bull; crisis management</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // <![CDATA[

            var so = new SWFObject("<?php print file_directory_path(); ?>/banner.swf", "ban", "702", "310", "8", "#ffffff");
            so.addParam('menu', 'false');
            so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
            so.addParam("base", "<?php print file_directory_path(); ?>");
            so.addVariable("banner_imgs", "<?php print $banner_imgs; ?>");
            so.write("banner");

            // ]]>
        </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding

```
shuffle($banner_imgs_array);
```

line just before

```
$banner_imgs = implode(',', $banner_imgs_array);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: this code is now live and it did seem to shuffle the array in the source, but for some reason the slideshow is still presenting the images in sequential order, even after clearing cache. perhaps the problem is elsewhere. thanks for your answer!

Comment: are you sure you put shuffle "BEFORE" the line? please try "echo $banner_imgs" after "$banner_imgs = implode(',', $banner_imgs_array);" and see if it is really shuffled in the string. maybe flash applet has an ordering feature. try to rename image files and see if that change the order.

Answer (score 0):

[array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) will return one or more random array keys. If you want to shuffle the array itself, use [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).